# matlab and enterprise applications

Tags: java, hibernate, matlab

I have long background in enterprise engineering, abut as circumstance has it have have found my role changing.  I have been tasked to lead a quantitative finance group, performing time series evaluation of proprietary data.

Our application stack (on the engineering side, which I have no influence on, but yet need to interface with) is JAVA (or SCALA) to Hibernate 3.x (annotations and xml) running on tomcat. Tons of experienced software guys...

I need data from them for two functions

1. research (i imagine pulling straight from the DB)
2. as parameters to any algorithms developed (described below)

My team is mostly folks with math and computational finance degrees, a couple w/ limited java experience (I have considerable .NET experience as well).

We are tasked to:

1. developed (multiple) algorithms that generate discreet trading signals (events) out of our underlying data
2. apply those algorithms to events coming from our web applications in real time
3. raise any trading signals (events) back to the application stack as they occur

   a. display events visually in the application

   b. send events to clients over the internet (somehow)

The best case is that any tool (MATLAB) used for the purpose of algorithm research and development, will also be used in the production environment - and be completely integrated to our production systems (as a listener to events, and then again as a source of events feeding back in).

The worst case is that any algorithm we develop needs to be reimplemented in the JAVA/SCALA space for integration.

My questions are

1. is matlab integration with java sufficient for this?  They are not using an application server (like JBOSS), so i guess each tomcat machine is logically and physically its own JVM instance. So I don't see any JVM constraints (as in MATLAB owning its own instance) as a major obstacle
2. has anybody interfaced matlab to a database over Hibernate?
3. does .NET a better choice for interfacing with matlab?  If so which features does it offer that java integration does not?
4. what capabilities are there in Matlab to "compile" your work into modules, and add to standard unit testing and automated build processes (ie HUDSON)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. MATLAB's Java integration is sufficient for your aims. There is no issue in using
   Java classes from the MATLAB JVM interacting with JBOSS as well.
2. Yes through JBOSS.
3. Never touched .NET, but you won't get the seamless support as seen for Java. Using Java you may use MATLAB as Java scripting engine, similar to projects like Groovy, or use instances of proxy classes using api calls.
4. Use [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) in order to generate Java classes from your MATLAB code. The compiled code may be tested with any black box testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #4: For testing inside the MATLAB environment, I recommend Steve Eddins' test framework: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846